# How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to use JavaScript with WebDriver (Selenium 2) using Java.

I've followed some a guide and on [*Getting Started* page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Getting_Started): there is an instruction at 1st line to run as:

```
$ ./go webdriverjs
```

My question: From which folder/location the command mentioned above will be run/executed?

Comment: Do you want to write your tests in JavaScript, or do you want to use Javascript commands in your test (written in Java)?

Comment: I want to use Javascript commands in my test (written in Java)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Based on your previous questions, I suppose you want to run JavaScript snippets from Java's `WebDriver`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The `WebDriverJs` is actually "just" another `WebDriver` language binding (you can write your tests in Java, C#, Ruby, Python, JS and possibly even more languages as of now). This one, particularly, is JavaScript, and allows you therefore to write tests in JavaScript.

If you want to run JavaScript code in Java `WebDriver`, do this instead:

```
WebDriver driver = new AnyDriverYouWant();
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("yourScript();");
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("This driver does not support JavaScript!");
}
```

I like to do this, also:

```
WebDriver driver = new AnyDriverYouWant();
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
} // else throw...

// later on...
js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('someId');");
```

You can find more documentation on this [here, in the documenation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#execute-script), or, preferably, [in the JavaDocs of `JavascriptExecutor`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).

The `executeScript()` takes function calls and raw JS, too. You can `return` a value from it and you can pass lots of complicated arguments to it, some random examples:

1.

```
    // returns the right WebElement
    // it's the same as driver.findElement(By.id("someId"))
    js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('someId');");
```

2. ```
    // draws a border around WebElement
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.anything("tada"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);
   ```
3. ```
    // changes all input elements on the page to radio buttons
    js.executeScript(
            "var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');" +
            "for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { " +
            "    inputs[i].type = 'radio';" +
            "}" );
   ```

Comment: This is helpful. if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)executeScript("yourScript();");
} "yourScript()" Is it Javascript function? If so, where can I write JS code?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim That's the nice thing! You can write any JS code into the `executeScript()` function. I added some examples.

Comment: I have the JS code as: <script>
function showAlert(){
alert('success');
}
</script> I want to use executeScript() as: JavascriptExecutor js =  (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("showAlert()"); What is the exact/proper syntax of writing the above JS code in Java code using WebDriver?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim If that function is embedded to your page, just do `js.executeScript("showAlert()");`. If it isn't, do `js.executeScript("function showAlert() { alert('success'); }; showAlert()");`

Comment: Thanks a lot. js.executeScript("function showAlert() { alert('success'); }; showAlert()"); is worked well. Alternatively, I want to write that JS code/function in my Java code separately and want to call JS function as js.executeScript("showAlert()");  What's the way/syntax of writing JS code/function in Java code separately?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim You can do `js.executeScript("window.showAlert = function() { alert('success'); };");` and then, anytime later, the call: `js.executeScript("showAlert()");`

Comment: nice. Again thanks. It is working very well & I have got the exact solution

Comment: So the first argument in the executeScript is the script itself that is method's body and the second argument is the method's arguments, right?

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic Yes. Or almost, in case you misunderstood a small detail. The first argument is the script, _any additional argument_ (second, third, etc.) is passed to the script (and is accessible via the magic `arguments` variable).

Comment: @Slanec can I ask when does selenium run the javascript? like is it after the the last function run of the page's javascript or...?

Comment: @richmondwang It runs it as soon as it can. Whether you tell Selenium to click an element or to run a piece of Javascript doesn't matter, both would be run the same time. Does that answer your question? What are you trying to achieve? What are you asking about?

Comment: @Slanec so it runs asynchronously with the page's javascripts? just wanted to know.

Comment: @PetrJaneček what if I need to include an external script from CDN url inside executeScript? How do I do that?

Comment: @Srk95 Hello! I'm sorry, this post is 9 years old now and I have not been using WebDriver or any other similar technology for more tha 7 years now. I simply don't know anymore. It's likely that because of the cross-domain policy you will not be able to do that at all? I found this old answer for injecting jQuery, perhaps it would still work after all those years: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/webdriver-can-i-inject-a-jquery-script-for-a-page-that-isnt-using-jquery

Answer (score 5):

**JavaScript With Selenium WebDriver**

*Selenium is one of the most popular automated testing suites. 
Selenium is designed in a way to support and encourage automation testing of functional aspects of web based applications and a wide range of browsers and platforms.*

```
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // This opens a window    
        String url = "----";


        /*driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("yashwanth.m");
        driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("yashwanth@123");*/

        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;       
        if (jse instanceof WebDriver) {
            //Launching the browser application
            jse.executeScript("window.location = \'"+url+"\'");
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('username').value = \"yash\";");
// Tag having name then
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='j_password']")).sendKeys("admin");


//Opend Site and click on some links. then you can apply go(-1)--> back  forword(-1)--> front.
//Refresheing the web-site. driver.navigate().refresh();            
jse.executeScript("window.history.go(0)");
            jse.executeScript("window.history.go(-2)");
            jse.executeScript("window.history.forward(-2)");

            String title = (String)jse.executeScript("return document.title");
            System.out.println(" Title Of site : "+title);

            String domain = (String)jse.executeScript("return document.domain");
            System.out.println("Web Site Domain-Name : "+domain);

            // To get all NodeList[1052] document.querySelectorAll('*');  or document.all
            jse.executeAsyncScript("document.getElementsByTagName('*')");

            String error=(String) jse.executeScript("return window.jsErrors");
            System.out.println("Windowerrors  :   "+error);



            System.out.println("To Find the input tag position from top"); 
            ArrayList<?> al =  (ArrayList<?>) jse.executeScript(
                    "var source = [];"+
                    "var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');"+
                    "for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { " +
                       "   source[i] = inputs[i].offsetParent.offsetTop" +      //"    inputs[i].type = 'radio';"
                    "}"+
                    "return source"                 
                    );//inputs[i].offsetParent.offsetTop     inputs[i].type

            System.out.println("next");
            System.out.println("array : "+al);

            // (CTRL + a) to access keyboard keys. org.openqa.selenium.Keys 
            Keys k = null;
            String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a");
            WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
            body.sendKeys(selectAll);

            // Search for text in Site. Gets all ViewSource content and checks their.
            if (driver.getPageSource().contains("login")) {
                System.out.println("Text present in Web Site");
            }

        Long clent_height = (Long) jse.executeScript("return document.body.clientHeight");
        System.out.println("Client Body Height : "+clent_height);

        // using selenium we con only execute script but not JS-functions.

    }
    driver.quit(); // to close browser
}
```

*To Execute User-Functions, Writing JS in to a file and reading as String and executing it to easily use.*

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("JsFile.txt")));
        String js_TxtFile = ""; 
            while (sc.hasNext()) {          
                String[] s = sc.next().split("\r\n");   
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    js_TxtFile += s[i];
                    js_TxtFile += " ";
                }           
            }
        String title =  (String) jse.executeScript(js_TxtFile);
        System.out.println("Title  : "+title);
```

*document.title & document.getElementById() is a property/method available in Browsers.*

*JsFile.txt*

```
var title = getTitle();
return title;

function getTitle() {
    return document.title;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try clicking by JavaScript:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("someid"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Also you can use jquery. In worst cases, for stubborn pages it may be necessary to do clicks by custom EXE application. But try the obvious solutions first.

Comment: this appears to be pausing for the length of time set by `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait`. Is this the case and if so, how to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see how to add parameters to the method call, it took me a while to find it, so I add it here.
How to pass parameters in (to the javascript function), use "arguments[0]" as the parameter place and then set the parameter as input parameter in the executeScript function.

```
    driver.executeScript("function(arguments[0]);","parameter to send in");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read text of any element using javascript executor, you can do something like following code:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='infaCompositeViewTitle']"));
String assets = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[1].textContent;", ele);
```

In this example, I have following HTML fragment and I am reading "156".

```
<div class="infaCompositeViewTitle">
   <span>All Assets</span>
   <span>156</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private WebDriver driver;

     public void LogInSuperAdmin() {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("console.log('Test test');");
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation and solved it like this:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to run this command in the top-level directory of a Selenium SVN repository checkout.