# How to getText() for XPath with attribute 'display:none'

Tags: java, selenium, dojo, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to use `getText()` for one XPath, need text what is there.

> //span(contains(@style,'display:none'))

XPath is working tested in firebug, I've tried `getText`, `getAttribute`, so far no luck

Comment: This link details how to use java's javascriptExecutor method:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java  To assist you further, we'll need to see the HTML, as barak has already noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to say without the exact HTML, which you have not specified in your question...

To begin with, you need to change this:

```
"//span(contains(@style,'display:none'))"
```

To this:

```
"//span[contains(@style,'display:none')]"
```

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, since the `span` element is not visible, you might be able to do it with:

```
String innerHTML = elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Where `elem` is the parent node of the `span` element.

Then, in order to get the actual text, you will need to parse the `innerHTML` string.

Comment: One thing, Selenium doesn't interact with elements that are not visible.  He's likely going to need to use a javascript executor solution.

Comment: Thank You barak but still I can not getText(). Richard could you please point me to this js solution?

Comment: @Karol: You might be able to do it with `String innerHTML = elem.getAttribute("innerHTML")`, where `elem` is the parent node of the `span` element.

Comment: `getAttribute("innerHTML")` will get eveything inside, which includes HTML for descendant nodes. I reckon `getAttribute("textContent")` is better.

Comment: @user1177636: Please note the last sentence in the answer: "In order to get the actual text, you will need to parse the `innerHTML` string". I'm not familiar with the `textContent` attribute, so thank you for the additional info :)

Comment: @barakmanos: Actually I need to take back what I've said. Using `textContent` will still need string parsing. The difference between `textContent` and `innerHTML` is about HTML tags. Parsing result from `textContent` will be easier by replacing inner nodes text with empty string without worrying about tags.

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is invisible (it has `display:none`), Selenium cannot natively interact with it.  You need cast your driver to `JavascriptExecutor`, then execute the following javascript:

```
$x("//span(contains(@style,'display:none'))")[0].text
```

The `[0]` returns the 1st element returned by the xpath.

This will return the inner text of the element.

Comment: Your xpath needs to be corrected to `$x("//span[contains(@style,'display:none')]").text`

Comment: I don't believe `$x` has anything to do with jQuery, it's specific to Chrome & Firefox (with Firebug)

Comment: @Richard, I don't believe so, as the xpath selector returns an array.

Comment: @Arran, I looked it up, and apparently, I'm mistaken.  Thanks.