# Make Selenium find checkbox with disabled="disabled"

Tags: selenium, xpath, checkbox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to grab a checkbox with `disabled="disabled"` attribute using:

```
 List<WebElement> checkBox= driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath"));
```

Where "xPath" is one of:

```
(.//*[contains(@class,'wfm-statusbar')])[1]/descendant::input

(.//*[contains(@class,'wfm-statusbar')])[1]/descendant::*[@type='checkbox']

(.//*[contains(@class,'wfm-statusbar')])[1]/descendant::*[@disabled='disabled']
```

**ALL** of the above **work** when checked in FirePath and Console. Example proof:

[image]

However, when I run the xPath in code, it fails:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for ...
```

If I search for a "normal" checkbox (without the disabled attribute and on the same page), code works. So I'm pretty sure it is this `disabled="disabled"` attribute that is to blame.

**Simplified HTML:**

```
<div class="wfm-statusbar">
  <div>
    <span>  some text</span>
    <span>
    <label>
           <input type="checkbox"  disabled="disabled" >
    </label>
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please explain "it fails"!

Comment: edited (added the exception)

Comment: Have you tried a longer wait?

Comment: @SiKing - I haven't as I find that 15 seconds is ample time to find the element. All other elements are found instantly with the exception of this case. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You will have to post a lot more information! The "disabled" suggests the element is ... disabled. Selenium generally does not permit interacting with disabled elements. Are you trying to click on it? Did you force it to enabled somehow?

Comment: The point is to enter the page and check that the checkbox is disabled. But I'm not even trying `.click()` or `isEnabled()` or anything as it is pointless because Selenium can't even locate in the first place.  I'm only trying to "grab it". I'd be happy if it would, as I could then save it to `List<WebElement> boxes` and then do `if(boxes.size()<1){ some logic}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a CSS selector but I don't expect that it will work if your XPath doesn't. As SiKing said, Selenium won't interact with disable or invisible elements.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.wfm-statusbar input[disabled='disabled']")).isEmpty());
```

This will return `true` if no elements are found.

You will likely have to access these elements using JS. You can find a question related to that here: [How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java).

You will want to use the same CSS Selector but using JS, as below.

```
document.querySelectorAll("div.wfm-statusbar input[disabled='disabled']");
```

This will return a collection of elements that you can do things with.

---

Here's a simple example of something similar to what you will want to use for `JavascriptExecutor`.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
List<WebElement> linksJs = (List<WebElement>) jse.executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll('a')");
System.out.println(linksJs.size());
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for the JavaScript suggestion. Can't run JS script as I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: [bla bla] ... cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor`. I've troubleshooted this issue but with no success. If I ever get it to work, I'll get back to this answer.

Comment: I added a quick example of JSE and how you will likely use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and only will get the checkbox if it is a checkbox and is disabled.

```
(.//*[contains(@class,'wfm-statusbar')])[1]/descendant::*[@type='checkbox' and @disabled='disabled']
```

Comment: There's no reason for this to work as it simply combines two non-working selectors into one. p.s. I tried it anyway and it doesn't work.

Comment: You said that both selectors worked when you checked them separately in firepath. You could try using `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);` then do `WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPATH("the xpath you are testing")));` and see if it even is visible.