# How to make Selenium ignore/skip or override window.close()

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium on Java to auto test a webpage, this page's script calls `window.close()` right after page is loaded.

```
            window.opener='whatever';
            window.open('','_parent','');
            window.close();
```

In IE9, it pops up a confirm dialog `"The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window disable"` with Yes/No options. Pressing Yes will close the webpage.

I don't want this closing (to keep the session) and neither the popup. Could you please suggest me a solution for ignore or override the `window.close()` script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply overwrite the `window.close` function with JavaScript.

```
String disableCloseScript = "window.close = function() { }";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(disableCloseScript);
```

Checkout these answers for more information:

- [How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)
- [JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried override the `window.close()` method by that way and it works on Chrome, not work on IE9. `window.close = function(){
     alert("hello");
     };
     
                window.opener='whatever';
                window.open('','_parent','');
                window.close();`
On Chrome, it shows the alert `hello`, but on IE9, it closes the webpage tab

Comment: Damn IE. Is the call to close in a function? If it is, you could try proxying the window object and ignore the `close()` call or regexp replace the call out.