# Reference selenium element in JavaScriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a list of elements, located in Selenium with the `By.CssSelector` method:

```
var contentRows = new List<TableRow>();

for (var i = 1; i < PositiveInfinity; i++)
{
    var cssSelectorToFind = $"tbody > tr:nth-child({i})";
    var bySelector = By.CssSelector(cssSelectorToFind);

    var rowElement = WebElement.FindElements(bySelector).ToArray();

    if (rowElement.Length == 1)
    {
        var description = $"{Description} Content row: {i}.  Selected by: {bySelector}.";

        var tableRow = new TableRow(bySelector, WebDriver, description, Headers);

        contentRows.Add(tableRow);
    }
    else
    {
        if (rowElement.Length == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The selector {bySelector} returned more that one row at the same ordinal position.  Should be impossible... Best look at the selector and the HTML.");
        }
    }
}

return contentRows;
```

For each of these rows I need to set a class in the HTML of `selected`.

I understand that I have to do this with the `JavaScriptExecutor`.

- Is there a way to get a reference to each of these so I can add this individually?
- Is the only way to give each row some unique ID and then use that in the JavaScrit?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `IWebElement` references as parameters to `ExecuteScript`, and then work with those in your JavaScript, if that's what you're looking for. So for example, if you have an `IWebElement` and want to highlight it by drawing a red border around it, you can do that with the following code (based on [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java):

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("..."));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);
```