# Selenium-Onclick() JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, webdriver

Following is my source code to select radio button having JavaScript `onclick()` method.

```
<span class="adControls">
<input id="RdbtnPreviousDate" name="date" value="RdbtnPreviousDate" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'RdbtnPreviousDate\',\'\')', 0)" type="radio"/>
<label for="RdbtnPreviousDate">27-Jul-2017</label>
</span>
```

I tried with all following but none of code run successfully.

1) `wbd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id=RdbtnPreviousDate]")).click();`

2) `wbd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=RdbtnPreviousDate]")).click();`

3)

```
wbd.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span[1]/input")).click();
```

4) `wbd.findElement(By.xpath("//[class='adControls'][@id='RdbtnPreviousDate']]")).click();`

5)

```
wbd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[onclick=javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'RdbtnPreviousDate\',\'\')', 0)]")).click();
```

6)

```
WebElement input = wbd.findElement(By.id("RdbtnNextDate"));
new Actions(wbd).moveToElement(input).click().perform();
```

Some of Errors:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: #RdbtnNextDate Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Given css selector
>   expression
>   "input[onclick=javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack('RdbtnPreviousDate','')',
>   0)]" is invalid:

Comment: thanks but select method also not worked.

Comment: Is this inside a frame? if yes you might have to switch to frame before you can find this.

Comment: Yes it is inside form element  :  <form id="form1" method="post" action="FlightTrack.aspx"><script type="text/javascript"><link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<table class="tabclr" cellspacing="0"  align="center" width="600px">
<tbody> <tr class="tletter"> <td class="text-right"> Flight Date   </td>
<td colspan="4"><span class="adControls"><input id="RdbtnPreviousDate" name="date" value="RdbtnPreviousDate" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'RdbtnPreviousDate\',\'\')', 0)" type="radio"> <label for="RdbtnPreviousDate">03-Aug-2017</label>

Comment: Thanks pls suggest

Comment: The entire code is inside Form tag and login/logout/clicking and opening a new page all has worked without considering a form tag.

Comment: Please paste the source code of whole page then I might be able to help you

Comment: I tried but not possible to post entire code due to  number of characters constraints....

Answer (score 0):

try to execute a simple javascript(jQuery) to select the radio button

```
wbd.executeScript("$('input[id=RdbtnPreviousDate]').click()");
```

Comment: Add Cast to 'wbd', ?

Comment: Showing red line under 'executeScript and when hover it "The method executeScript(String) is undefined for the type WebDriver 1. Quick fix available   - Add Cast to 'wbd'".

Comment: What kind of webdriver do you use?? I didn't know some of drivers doesn't support executeScript.. Try with another web driver.

Comment: jre1.8.0_91 ,  selenium-server3.3.1, Mozilla-52.0, Eclipse neon

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java  this looks helpful

Comment: i tried with        if (wbd instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
      ((JavascriptExecutor)wbd).executeScript("$('input[id=RdbtnPreviousDate]').click()");
  } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("This driver does not support JavaScript!");
  }   Also tried  with  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) wbd;  
      js.executeScript("$('input[id=RdbtnPreviousDate]').click()");    No error and button didnt get selected.

Comment: js.executeScript("setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'RdbtnPreviousDate\',\'\')', 0)"); is this work?

Comment: jesuisgenial, tried but  no error and also not radio button get selected.