# How to trigger Google Tag Manager script from java code

Tags: javascript, java, google-analytics

I need to automate web analytics and for that I need to trigger "Google Tag Manager" GTM script from java code.
e.g.

- User goes to https://www.etsy.com/
- User looks for script of GTM which is dataLayer

**`(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KWW5SS');`**

- I can goto chrome console and type **dataLayer**, press ENTER key to see the values

How can I do this from Java code ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but it sounds like you are looking for something like Selenium webdriver (an automation tool that can call a website and execute scripts there).  It has a function that can return the value of javascript variables in the page. My only experience is in Python so I can't help with the Java part, but searching for "Selenium Webdriver Java" on SO should give you some results.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I did search but couldn't find Java solution to call javascript object and extract values. Please share your python solution here

Comment: There is a question/answer that might help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java. In Python you can use the executeScript to pass "return <variable name>" in as a parameter and it returns the value for use in the python programm. I assume it works similar in Java.

Comment: @EikePierstorff solution you posted executes javascript on particular element, in my case I just want to execute in stand alone mode to fetch value out of it

Comment: No, not really. In Python I can do driver.execute_script("return window.dataLayer") and that will return the JSON from the dataLayer as a dict. As I understand the question that I have linked this should work similiarly in Java.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks for your pointers. I could get it working as below ArrayList<Class> myList = new ArrayList<Class>();
myList =  (ArrayList) js.executeScript("return window.dataLayer");   Now next challenge is to extract data in optimized way as has got key-value pairs with some each key having different number of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could achieve with below code

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();

        ArrayList<Map<String, List<String> >> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Execute GTM script to fetch values       
        myList =  (ArrayList) js.executeScript("return window.dataLayer");

        // Parse through GTM arrayList  
        for(int a=0; a < myList.size(); a++) {
            for (String key : myList.get(a).keySet()) {
                System.out.println(key + "      " + myList.get(a).get(key));

            }
        }

         //Next Step
         // assert against expected values
```