# How to use following JS code line with java selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, tabs, console

**Description:** 
I am using following JS code line using chrome console (whose image is also attached) and the this code gives ids of opened Tabs in a page of my web application (tabs image is also attached to understand output). But Now I don't know how to use this JS code line in my automation script that I am writing using Selenium Web-driver in Java.

**Code:**

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[class*='x-tab x-unselectable x-tab-after-title x-box-item x-tab-default x-top x-tab-top x-tab-default-top x-closable x-tab-closable x-tab-default-closable x-closable-top x-tab-closable-top x-tab-default-closable-top x-icon-text-left x-tab-icon-text-left x-tab-default-icon-text-left']")).map(function(item){return item.id;})

[Tabs screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EuFV.png)

**Question:**

Can anybody tell me how to use this code line in selenium Webdriver script using Java?
I am using above JS code line on chrome console opened for my application and it is giving correct result.

[Output of above code line using chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Qn8.png)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: Did you google this at all? A simple google of "java selenium execute javascript" returns all kinds of results that answer this question.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for comment. yes I googled it. but could not get success and that's why I asked here. and Screenshot is just the output of the above pasted code. If you can help, then please let me know the solution of that. Thanks

Comment: Also, I have edited my question.

Comment: @Engineer Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `executeScript` method like this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); //click the WebElement via Javascript.
```

In your case, your code would look like this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(\"[class*='x-tab x-unselectable x-tab-after-title x-box-item x-tab-default x-top x-tab-top x-tab-default-top x-closable x-tab-closable x-tab-default-closable x-closable-top x-tab-closable-top x-tab-default-closable-top x-icon-text-left x-tab-icon-text-left x-tab-default-icon-text-left']\")).map(function(item){return item.id;})");
```

`executeScript` returns an instance of `Object`, so in order to work with it, you would have to save the array in a variable and make a cast to `ArrayList`. You have to add `return` inside your javascript to tell WebDriver that this method will return something.

Try the following:

```
List<String> listOfIds = (List<String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(\"[class*='x-tab x-unselectable x-tab-after-title x-box-item x-tab-default x-top x-tab-top x-tab-default-top x-closable x-tab-closable x-tab-default-closable x-closable-top x-tab-closable-top x-tab-default-closable-top x-icon-text-left x-tab-icon-text-left x-tab-default-icon-text-left']\")).map(function(item){return item.id;})");
```

I will show you a warning `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<String>` and I don't know how to provide a checked cast. However, this should work.