# Existing value cannot be cleared in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to:

- Clear an existing value in the text box (to be specific, this is a **first name** field)
- Then save it with no value in the text box.

But somehow `clear();` does not clears the existing value. It retains the existing value **(first name)**.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("PrimaryContact_FirstName_Value")).clear();
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the **relevant** html ? And Possibly the URL if available.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately I am not able to provide the things you asked for...I am sorry. I am not sure if I can share those here.  Do you have any idea why this does not work? Or is it hard to tell without the html or the URL?

Comment: It will be very hard to know what's going on without seeing the html. If you could just copy the full HTML of the element you are trying to clear that would greatly help. Without that I will try my best to answer blindly.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot share the copy of the html for some personal reason...I would appreciate if you could share your guesses with me.. Thank you.

Comment: There may be an issue with masking; try using .SendKeys(Keys.Control, "a").SendKeys(Keys.Backspace) to the control and see if that works

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried it, but did not work. Thank you though.

Comment: I am sorry for the late comment, but the below code worked! Thank you so much Rescis.        .sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"a").sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context of the site/element, I will do my best to help you through this.

First let's try this to see if it clears the **text**:

```
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("PrimaryContact_FirstName_Value"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = ''", element));
```

---

**EDIT:**

Does it give you any errors?
Does it look like this?

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="get">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Send form data!">
</form>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using Java for this. I assume the code you shared works with JavaScript?? I am REALLY new to programming, so please correct me if I am mistaken, thank you for your help!

Comment: It's okay, it is Java code, look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java) for more information on executing js commands from java. The code below is asking if your html looks similar to that?

Comment: If your given locator `By.id("PrimaryContact_FirstName_Value")` indeed find the exact element,  This solution should fix your problem.  First of all, confirm your given locator is correct and the firstname box not inside frame

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I don't have access to Selenium until next Thursday, I will leave a comment as soon as I try your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you everyone who gave me comments. This issue was solved with the code below.   .sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"a").sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned *this is a first name field* it is highly possible you are trying to interact with the element before it is interactable. So you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be *clickable*.

As per your attempted code block you can use the following code block based on a `xpath` to clear the existing text :

```
WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='PrimaryContact_FirstName_Value']")));
myElement.click();
myElement.clear();
```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, thank you for your comment. I don't have access to Selenium until next Thursday, I will leave a comment here as soon as I try the code! Thank you.