# Create a function of a block of JavaScript code in selenium web driver with java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I have this piece of JavaScript code that I run in chrome console to add all the values of a column from a web table:

```
var iRow = document.getElementById("DataTable").rows.length
var sum = 0
var column = 5
for (i=1; i<iRow; i++){
    var retail = document.getElementById("DataTable").rows[i].cells.item(5).innerText
    var splitRetailPrice = retail.split(" ")
    for(j=0; j<splitRetailPrice.length; j++){
        var trimValue = splitRetailPrice[1]
        var intPrice = Number(trimValue)
        sum += intPrice
        break
    }
}
console.log(sum)
```

If I do it traditionally in selenium webdriver with a locator, ex: driver.findElement...., it takes me more than 5 minutes to complete the task cause the web table reproduces more than 7 thousand rows. I'm assuming this will make it much faster.

Question: How can I run this piece of code in selenium using java?

Question: Would it be a good idea?

I know it has something to do with JavascriptExecutor but I don't know how to implement it.

I see everyone is demonstrating one line of code everywhere with a return. It will be helpful if someone can show me how to incorporate multiple lines of codes given above and return the value. Preferably in a method which will return the value.

## SECOND ATTEMPT:

I've tried this now, following what was suggested as duplicate :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String val = (String) js.executeScript(
        "return"+
        "var iRow = document.getElementById('DataTable').rows.length"+
        "var sum = 0"+
        "for (i=1; i<iRow; i++){"+
            "var retail = document.getElementById('DataTable').rows[i].cells.item(5).innerText"+
            "var splitRetailPrice = retail.split("+" "+")"+ //passing a space as a delimiter.
            "for(j=0; j<splitRetailPrice.length; j++){"+
                "var trimValue = splitRetailPrice[1]"+
                "var intPrice = Number(trimValue)"+
                "sum += intPrice"+
                "break"+
            "}"+
        "}");

System.out.println(val);
```

I'm getting: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem like this. I will share it here in case this helps someone.

```
public int sumCost() {

 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 Long rows = (Long) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('DataTable').rows.length");
 int retailSum = 0;

 for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
  String retail = (String) js.executeScript(
   "return document.getElementById('DataTable').rows[" + i + "].cells.item(5).innerText"); //6th column
  String[] splitRetailPrice = retail.split(" "); //split the actual value
  int intPrice = Integer.valueOf(splitRetailPrice[1]);
  retailSum += intPrice;
 }
 return retailSum;
}
```